# How to get all has_many associations from an active record collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two models with `has_many through` associations; `Taskflows` and `Datasets`. They has a join table called `DatasetAssignments`.

I get all Taskflows using:

`@taskflows = Taskflows.all`

I know it's possible to get associations from a single ActiveRecord object, eg:

`@taskflow.datasets`

but is it possible to get all associated `Datasets` from the `@taskflows` ActiveRecord collection? Such as `@taskflows.datasets`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Models:

```
class Dataset < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dataset_assignments
  has_many :taskflows, :through => :dataset_assignments
end

class Taskflow < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dataset_assignments
  has_many :datasets, :through => :dataset_assignments
end

class DatasetAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dataset
  belongs_to :taskflow
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that `@taskflows` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, you can do this:

```
@datasets = Dataset.joins(:dataset_assignments).
    where(dataset_assignments: {taskflow: @taskflows.joins(:datasets) })
```

or, in the other direction:

```
@taskflows = Taskflow.joins(:dataset_assignments).
    where(dataset_assignments: {dataset: @datasets.joins(:taskflows) })
```

`joins` generates `INNER JOIN`s through many-to-many table and having the receiver being an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation` will preserve other conditions.

As @oreoluwa suggested, you can avoid N+1 queries when enumerating by using `includes`:

```
@taskflows = Taskflow.joins(...).includes(:datasets)
```

Comment: thanks, is there a difference between doing `@datasets.joins(:taskflows)` and `@datasets.joins(@taskflows)` - the @taskflows coming from a previous query?

Comment: Hold on, there is an issue with this. You're getting the same class records as your receiver. When `@datasets` is receiver, the datasets is what you're getting, but you need the taskflows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this, unless you have an outer model, let's call it User, where:

```
User
  has_many :taskflows
  has_many :datasets, through: :taskflows
```

or better let your `DatasetAssignment` belong to the user and fetch all `dataset_assignments` of a particular User.

Another approach would be to do a `@taskflows.map(&:datasets)`, but it's not effecient.

Or if you only need the `datasets` to render somewhere and are bothered about effeciency, you should use the `AR#includes` method like:

`@taskflow.includes(:datasets)`